# Modelling electrical conductivity in low-dimensional nanostructures

Tags: electrical-resistance, boltzmann-equation, quantum-transport, transport-phenomena

I know that the Boltzmann transport equation can be solved under the Relaxation Time Approximation (RTA) to obtain the electrical properties of materials. However, the parameter that I am interested in is the electrical conductivity whereas the RTA cannot go anywhere beyond the `electrical conductivity /relaxation time` and so the actual electrical conductivity can only be obtained if the relaxation time is known from either theory or experiments.

Is there any tool/method which can be used to evaluate either the relaxation time or the electrical conductivity of 1D and 2D nanostructures?

I am using the [SIESTA](https://siesta-project.org/siesta/) dft package as other plane-wave options are not feasible at the system sizes that I am working on.

Comment: You may like to also consider the new Matter Modelling SE https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I have already posted there as well. However nobody seems to be familiar with the process.